# UNLOAD in interactive SQL within a loop

Tags: while-loop, sqlanywhere

i wan't to do the following: Exporting a large table to filesystem getting some response from the db.

For this i tried to unload the table in chunks (see code below)

I tried the statements in Sybase Central - Interactive SQL and it keeps complaining that there is a syntax error at the unload line ( odbc sstatus 42000)

If i execute only the commented line, it does what i want for the first 1000 lines. So the syntax itself seems correct.
What am I missing (or is there an easier way to get feedback from a very long running db command?)

```
CREATE VARIABLE  @max_id INT;
CREATE VARIABLE  @min_id INT;
CREATE VARIABLE  @start_id INT;
CREATE VARIABLE  @end_id INT;
SELECT  @min_id = min(id) , @max_id = max(id) FROM testtable;
SELECT  @start_id = @min_id , @end_id   = @min_id + 1000 ;
//UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id BETWEEN @start_id AND @end_id) TO 'c:\temp\test.dat' ENCODING 'UTF8' APPEND ON;

WHILE    @end_id <= @max_id 
BEGIN
    UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id BETWEEN @start_id AND @end_id) TO 'c:\temp\test.dat' ENCODING 'UTF8' APPEND ON;
    SELECT  @start_id = @end_id + 1 ;
    SELECT  @end_id   = @end_id + 1000 ;
    MESSAGE convert(varchar, @start_id);
END;
```

---

EDIT:

```
WHILE    @end_id <= @max_id LOOP
...
END LOOP;
```

seems to do what i want in interactive sql, but what i is the error in the first part? with loop it does not work from an external command (e.g. calling BeginExecuteNonQuery)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VARIABLE  @max_id INT;
CREATE VARIABLE  @min_id INT;
CREATE VARIABLE  @start_id INT;
CREATE VARIABLE  @end_id INT;
SELECT  @min_id = min(id) , @max_id = max(id) FROM testtable;
SELECT  @start_id = @min_id , @end_id   = @min_id + 1000 ;
//UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id BETWEEN @start_id AND @end_id) TO 'c:\temp\test.dat' ENCODING 'UTF8' APPEND ON;

WHILE    @end_id <= @max_id Loop
    UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id BETWEEN @start_id AND @end_id) TO 'c:\temp\test.dat' ENCODING 'UTF8' APPEND ON;
    SET @start_id = @end_id + 1 ;
    SET @end_id   = @end_id + 1000 ;
END Loop;
```

Please find the corrected code. Just out of curiosity, is there a specific reason behind unloading in chunk?

Comment: the reason is that this is a command which will take a long time to be executed (in the code above it is scaled down, think about a little bit more complex SELECT with JOINS and a few hunderthousend lines in tables). To give some feedback "MESSAGE" is used to send information about actual state to client.

Comment: By the way, did my answer help at all. I am just curious.